# Error in typescript: property .ref does not exist on type 'AngularFireStorageModule'

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic3, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I'm trying to upload images to firebase with AngularFire in Ionic, but I keep getting the error `'Property '.ref' does not exist on type 'AngularFireStorageModule'.'`.

**Imports:**

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from 'angularfire2/storage';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { enableLogging } from '@firebase/database-types';
```

**Error on .ref**

```
 for(var i = 0; i < this.imagePaths.length; i++){
    console.log("Adding photo's" + this.imagePaths[i]);
        const filePath = 'images/' + this.docRef + '/';
        const ref = this.storage.ref(filePath);
        const task = ref.put(this.imagePaths[i]).then((snapshot) => {
          console.log('Uploaded an image!');
        });
  }
```

The error happens on the line `const ref = this.storage.ref(filePath);`

Does anybody know why this won't work? I searched online but all of the tutorials did everything just the same way that I did.

Comment: Where have you declared this.storage?

Comment: In my constructor: constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public navParam: NavParams,
    public imagePicker: ImagePicker, public addHouseObject: AddHouseService, public afs: AngularFirestore, public userService: UserService,
     public datePipe: DatePipe, public storage: AngularFireStorageModule)

Comment: I think you incorrectly have an instance of the module injected into your component. You should instead import `AngularFireStorage` instead of `AngularFireStorageModule`, changing the constructor paremeter type as well.

Comment: Yep, that was it, I imported the wrong type. Thank you! @DanielWStrimpel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';
constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage)

uploadFile(file){
  const filePath = 'images/' + this.docRef + '/';
  const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);

  task.percentageChanges().subscribe(per => {
    console.log(per);
  });

  task.downloadURL().subscribe(url => {
    console.log(url);
  }
}
```

source [AngularFire2 Docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md)